# How to split traffic in Google AppEngine for specific IP addresses

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find a way to split the Google AppEngine for some Ip address for testing purpose is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to split the incoming traffic between several GAE app/service versions based on the IP address from which the requests originate. From [Splitting traffic across multiple versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic):

> When you have specified two or more versions for splitting, you must
>   choose whether to split traffic by using either an IP address or HTTP
>   cookie. It's easier to set up an IP address split, but a cookie split
>   is more precise. For more information, see [IP address splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic#ip_address_splitting)
>   and [Cookie splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic#cookie_splitting).

Read the respective linked section (same page) for details and limitations.

Configuring the traffic split is done from the [Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) page.